# Connection to tcp://smtp.mail.yahoo.com:465 Timed Out

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-5, smtp

I'm really struggling with this error :

> Swift_TransportException in AbstractSmtpTransport.php line 404:
>   Connection to tcp://smtp.mail.yahoo.com:465 Timed Out

I hope someone can shed some light on this.

Here are my settings in my `.env` file

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mail.yahoo.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=dev.email@yahoo.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=******
```

Comment: check this out: https://help.yahoo.com/kb/SLN4075.html, did you enable SSL? MAIL_ENCRYPTION=SSL

Comment: I forgot to add the detail that this is happening in my local env.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

I notice in `/config/mail.php` , I see

`'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),`

By updating it to

`'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'ssl'),`

Now, it is working fine. My email is sending out now.

Comment: You can do that also in the `.env file`

`MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl`

Comment: By doing this, my error has been gone but email not sent. I am using my domain email server.

Comment: Really helpful for my Laravel 5.5 app.

Comment: Nothing but this helped me for Laravel 7

Comment: I used 465 and 587 with SSL and TLS both.
But failed. It is working on my local but doesn't work on server. It's funny.

My Laravel version is 8.x
Any help?

Answer (score 20):

With Laravel 6.x ,7.x , 8.x and 9.x

it is advisable to use SSL over the default tls.

Most shared hosting providers sign emails with SSL so edit your .env file to have this

```
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

Comment: Also, the port for SSL should be used

Comment: Modern email servers use **port 587** for the secure submission

Comment: Yeah, that's true but then I had issues trying to use port 587, the connection to the mail server always timed out. It was working fine but then it stopped all of a sudden. I changed to 465 and it worked just fine. Your comment made me read up a little bit about [difference between port 587 and 465](https://sendgrid.com/blog/whats-the-difference-between-ports-465-and-587/)

Answer (score 0):

**Just Use**
**`MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls`** to **`MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl`**

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mail.yahoo.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=dev.email@yahoo.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=******
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

Comment: How this answer is different from above ones?